# CSS and JS merging options is not working on Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, merge-css

I am simply trying to enable the option of **merging JS** and **CSS** on **configuration > system > developer** and I have cleared the cache and even tried to delete the VAR folder and still having CSS and JS not merged.

How can I diagnose this problem or there any advice that could fix it?

Comment: You can try clearing your browser cache and cookies

Comment: Thank you for your reply i have erased the cache nothing happened view-source:https://ragtime.online/

Comment: did you check the settings for every configuration scope? try changing the configuration scope dropdown on the settings page and make sure the settings are not being overridden at store or store-view level.

Comment: I checked what i figure it out it was a missing ; that was preventing all file to get merged is that correct does it prevent a ";" from getting files merged ?